# JSON - How to reference using a wildcard?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a large JSON object where I can access the the value I want like so:

`$scope.customers[1][data]["DisplayName"];`

However, that references the `DisplayName` of only one object.

Is there an easy way to return all `DisplayName` properties from the entire collection?

i.e.

`$scope.customers[*][data]["DisplayName"];`

Or is the only way to do this by creating a new JSON object by looping through the original?

Comment: Looping/filtering is the only way. You may find helper methods or modules that simplify it, but in the end they're all going to loop over it.

Comment: Is there a filter available in Angular that can do this?

Comment: Yeah, `ng-repeat will do that for you.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah `[].map` would likely be easier to implement than any filter angular has. `var displayNames = $scope.customers.map(function (d) {return d[data]["DisplayName"];});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function of Array. It applies the callback function to each element of array and produces new array:

```
[1,2,3].map(function(num) { return num * num }); // returns [1, 4, 9]
```

In your case you can use:

```
$scope.customers.map(function(element) { return element[data]["DisplayName"]; } );
```